# Google Spreadsheet/Excel filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

As you can see in [this image](https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B-_4DbHS-aZPbmtXcFFneHZjTTA/excel_0002_Layer%200.jpg) I have spreadsheet of many athlets, that will participate in competition.

My task is using groups (or ranges) DISCIPLINAS (en. Disciplines), which contains **100m** run, **400m** run ... **javelin** and combine with range GRUPAS (en. Groups), which contains **A gr. boys**, **A gr. girls** ... **Females**, filter athlets on [this](https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B-_4DbHS-aZPbmtXcFFneHZjTTA/excel_0000_Layer%202.jpg) table.

Is it possible that on table which is visible in previous image choose for example Discipline **100m** and Group **Vīrietis**, then this chart will populate data from first sheet **DATA** using rows 2, 28, 36 and so on, but not only hiding other rows, but just put values on this sheet.

I've tried VLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH functions, but without any luck. Maybe you have some ideas to share.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create Pivot Tables, with a tabular layout to do this.  Just add each of the columns you need as "columns", filter the proper values.  You don't need anything as "values"

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the range to a table using Insert / Table.  Then each column heading will become a filter where you can make your selections to restrict the rows shown.